# Time complexity of batch gradient descent

Tags: optimization, convergence, gradient-descent, stochastic-gradient-descent, time-complexity

I am read http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4937-accelerating-stochastic-gradient-descent-using-predictive-variance-reduction.pdf paper. It states that "Due to the poor condition number, the standard batch gradient descent requires complexity of $n \log(1/\epsilon)$ iterations over the
data to achieve accuracy of $\epsilon$, which means we have to process $n^2 \log(1/\epsilon)$ number of examples". Can anyone explain how they got $n \log(1/\epsilon)$ complexity?

Also, in general, how do we find iteration complexity of given stochastic gradient descent? I am reading http://proceedings.mlr.press/v80/natole18a/natole18a.pdf paper which uses stochastic gradient descent where they have $O(1/T)$ convergence rate. For this they have given the following theorem:

$$E[\|w_{T+1}-w^* \|^2] \leq \frac{ t_0}{T}E[\|w_{0}-w^* \|^2]$$

where $W^*$ is the optimal value, $t_0$ is a constant and $w_0$ is the starting point. But I don't know how to find iteration complexity from above theorem.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?  From my standpoint, the JMLR paper discusses the rate at which the error descreases with *every SGD iteration* while the NIPS paper discusses the number of elementary computations required to perform one of (those) SGD iterations.